# Energy states and electron excitation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, orbital-motion, atomic-physics, hydrogen

We all know that in Bohr's model for hydrogen like species , electrons can revolve in only those orbits where its angular momentum is an integral multiple of $\hbar=h/2\pi$. But suppose we provide the electron in hydrogen atom ground state an energy such that its resultant total energy doesn't match with any of the higher orbit energies. Will it jump to a higher level or the energy will not be utilized?

Comment: How come so many still refer to the Bohr Model? Do some education systems lag behind current theory *that much?*

Answer (score 2):

First, the Bohr atom model is not correct. Its lowest energy state has angular momentum $\hbar$. But this is not further relevant here.

If you provide an energy to the atom in the ground state which does not correspond to the energy difference to a higher energy state and is lower than the ionization energy (for example by a photon) your electron will not "accept" this energy and there will, in general, be no jump to a higher energy level. This is the reason why the hydrogen atom has sharp absorption lines lines in its spectrum.